# Given homomorphism $\rho: G \times H \to G$, trouble verifying Homomorphism Theorem

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

I've just run into a little confusion when doing questions on the Homomorphism Theorem.

Say we have a homomorphism $\rho: G \times H \to G$ such that $\rho(g,h) = g,$ where $G \times H$ represents the direct product of groups $G$ and $H$. Then the kernel of $\rho$ will be all elements of $G \times H$ of the form $(e, h)$. So this includes $(e, e)$.

The Homomorphism Theorem states that $\operatorname{image}(\rho)$ is isomorphic to $(G \times H) / \ker(\rho)$.

In this case $\operatorname{image}(\rho) = G$. So $G$ is isomorphic to $(G \times H) / \ker(\rho)$. But if $\ker(\rho)$ contains the identity of $G \times H$ then it seems that $(G \times H) / \ker(\rho)$ does not contain an identity element. How can $(G \times H) / \ker(\rho)$ be isomorphic to $G$ if it doesn't contain an identity element?

Obviously something in my thought process is wrong so I was hoping someone could help me realise my error :)

Comment: You should read an introduction to MathJax (like [MathJax help](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and use it to format your question.

Comment: Thank you, will read up on it now

Comment: Do you understand the notion of a quotient group? Maybe this is where your confusion comes from: $(G\times H)/ker(\rho)$ is the group of equivalence classes of $(G\times H)$, where two elements of $(G\times H)$ are in the same equivalence class if they differ by an element of $ker(\rho)$. Do not mix this up with $(G\times H)\setminus ker(\rho)$ which is just the set $(G\times H)$ without the set $ker(\rho)$ (which can never be a group if $\rho$ is a homomorphism)

Comment: That is absolutely where my confusion came from, I was misunderstanding the notation, so thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$G\times H/ker(\rho)$ *does* contain an identity element - namely, $[(e, e)]_\rho$, the equivalence class of $(e, e)$ modulo "is sent to the same element by $\rho$."

More generally, if $J$ is any group and $\varphi$ is a homomorphism from $J$, then $J/ ker(\varphi)$'s identity element is $[e_J]_\varphi$ - the equivalence class of the identity element $e_J\in J$, modulo (the equivalence relation induced by) $\varphi$.

Elements in the kernel don't *cease to exist*, they just *get mapped to the identity* (which, arguably confusingly, is called "vanishing," but it doesn't mean that they're no longer there).